# Are deep neural networks taught layer by layer or all layers at once?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to grasp the concepts of deep neural networks. When they are explained, they basically say that each layer of the network represents one level of abstraction, for example, the first layer is about edges, next layer is about shapes, like wheels and the next layer about what the wheels add up to, like a car.

This image pretty much represents the concept:
[image]

When figuring out the weights for each layer, is this done one layer at the time or all layers together. Do you first run the AI on a set of images labeled with different kinds of edges and then a set of images labeled with things like wheels and then on a set of images labeled with cars or do you let the network figure that out for itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not provide deep nets with supervision on each layer, this would be too complex in terms of building the dataset. What you see on these slides is interpretation of what is happening **on its own**, not what **we enforce**. There are both layer-by-layer techniques (less popular now) and everything-jointly (popular know), but neither of them use additional supervision, you do not tell network to extract edges, it simply emerges from the optimization problem and network structure in practise.

However, there are also deep architectures that do not have this property, like https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09382 or in general - recurrent nets (which are also "deep" in this sense). Thus do not treat this as a property of the deep learning, this is simply **a common empirical observation when dealing with particular data**, nothing less and nothing more.

Comment: This was very helpful! When training a single-layer network, I understand how you can use something like gradient descent to figure out how to change the weights properly, but if you have hidden layers, you don't know what you are optimizing for, how do you know how to change each weight. This is probably a topic of it's own but if you could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: I can see your confusion here. When you have a single hidden layer you also do not have a supervision, you do not know what is the expected activation, you only know correct answer onthe top layer. So what you do? You just compute gradients wrt parameters. Nothing changes when you have more layers. There is still a single supervision at the top and you compute gradient wrt all parameters. There are tricks to do it efficiently (backprop) but this the same thing from math perspective. You just need partail derivatives. Thus you treat all other weoghts as constants and differentiate